What legal reason, if any, does my bank have to know if I am a dual citizen of the US?
I am a US citizen permanently living overseas, and maintain a bank account in the US. I was recently prompted to update my personal information, and one of items I had to answer was whether I had dual citizenship with any other country. (I do not.)
I know that being a US citizen living outside the US subjects me to certain tax and financial reporting laws, so I understand the bank's need to know if I am a US citizen, but I do not understand the need to know about other citizenship. My understanding is that US law on principle does not take into account any other citizenship in any way; a US dual citizen is, as far as the law is concerned, only a US citizen. Having any other citizenship should not subject me to any additional legal obligations or relieve me of any.
What legal reason is there, if any, for the question about dual citizenship?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

As stated in this answer, there is a provision in tax law with regard to expatriation that specifically addresses dual citizens at birth of the US and other countries.
I will accept that the bank required the information for purposes of this law.

That's not really relevant to the bank, however.

@phoog It might be if the US government decides to audit you. It might also be required for things like calculating the amount of money you have available to repay loans, etc.

@nick012000 it's not relevant to anyone unless and until the dual citizen renounces US citizenship, and after that point it continues to be irrelevant to the bank; it is a matter between the taxpayer and the IRS.  Similarly, banks do not ask account holders whether they are blind even though blindness affects tax liability.

@phoog Normally there would be no circumstances in which the US government would ask a US citizen about their dual citizenship. The government deputizes the banks to obtain this information preemptively in case the account holder is ever subject to the law.

@PaulRichter, I don't believe the U.S. government has deputized the banks to carry out any policing responsibilities whatsoever - for any agency. More accurately, they've effectively been told them to police themselves or face the consequences if they are indeed complicit in any illegal acts - even if only due to lack of due diligence. No bank will ever play the role of the IRS. The legal consequences of doing something like that could be disastrous for them as they would certainly be breaking a wide swath of laws.

@PaulRichter doubtful.  If a US citizen renounces US nationality, the burden of proof will be on the former US citizen to show that expatriation tax is not applicable.  It is in the former US citizen's interest to establish the facts of any other nationality if it triggers the exception.  The evidence would be submitted as part of the taxpayer's tax return submitted to the Internal Revenue Service.  The bank isn't involved at all.

@phoog The bank cares about your income when they're deciding whether or not to give you a loan. If you're a US citizen, they also need to take your US taxes into account when deciding if a loan would be affordable to you - US citizens always pay US tax rates unless the taxes of the country theyre living in are higher.

@nick012000 the question is about someone whom the bank knows to be a US citizen being asked to disclose other citizenship.  Furthermore the context is not a loan application, which requires much more disclosure, including copies of tax filings in many cases.  The question concerns a deposit account.  Banks do not ask for information from depositors just because the information might be useful if the depositor decides to apply for a loan at some point in the future.

Sanctions
While most sanctions are targeted, the US does have some
“comprehensively sanctioned jurisdictions”. So, for example, if your dual nationality is with Iran or Cuba, your bank can’t deal with you without additional paperwork.

Under KYC (Know your Customer) regulations, banks need to collect enough information to be in compliance with US law.. other countries generally have similar regulations. Here is Dow Jones' interpretation:

Customer Identification Program At the minimum, firms must pull four
pieces of identifying information about a client, including name, date
of birth, address, and identification number.
Most firms take additional steps in their screening process. Many will
make sure that clients do not appear on government sanction lists,
politically exposed person (PEP) lists, or known terrorism lists—
those who do appear usually require enhanced due diligence.
Other items considered at this time include financial transactions,
which firms use to separate potentially risky behavior from regular
business activity.
Much of this information comes from various reporting agencies, public
databases and third-party sources.
Customer Due Diligence (CDD) Customer due diligence is the process of
classifying all the information collected during the Customer
Identification Program.
Firms examine the nature and beneficiaries of existing relationships
to ensure all activity is consistent with historical customer
information.
The goal is to obtain enough information to verify a customer’s
identity and assess their riskiness. Since financial crime happens
quickly, firms frequently monitor this information for unusual spikes
in activity or changes to sanction lists. Most clients pose little to
no risk, but the few who do are subject to enhanced due diligence.
Enhanced Due Diligence (EDD) If a customer is believed to pose
additional risks, firms take extra steps to gain a better
understanding of their motivations. A high-risk person may include
those with political exposure or relationships with designated
persons. Even someone in a high-risk country can raise a red flag for
compliance.
In practice, firms must demonstrate a deeper understanding of the
high-risk clients identified by a standard customer due diligence
program. Some of the information required to perform enhanced due
diligence includes a source of wealth verification, detailed
management reports and relevant third-party research.

More prescriptive requirements can be found, for example, in Australian legislation (emphasis added):

KYC information means ‘know your customer information’ and may include
information in relation to matters such as:
(1) In relation to a customer who is an individual:
(a) the customer’s name;
(b) the customer’s residential address;
(c) the customer’s date of birth;
(d) any other name that the customer is known by;
(e) the customer’s country(ies) of citizenship;
(f) the customer’s country(ies) of residence;
(g) the customer’s occupation or business activities;
(h) the nature of the customer’s business with the reporting entity –
including:
(i) the purpose of specific transactions; or
(ii) the expected nature and level of transaction behaviour;
(i) the income or assets available to the customer;
(j) the customer’s source of funds including the origin of funds;
(k) the customer’s financial position;
(l) the beneficial ownership of the funds used by the customer with
respect to the designated services; and
(m) the beneficiaries of the transactions being facilitated by the
reporting entity on behalf of the customer including the destination
of funds.

Generally, financial institutions are conservative by nature, and a foreign-resident customer is already presenting a red flag. Less prescriptive requirements mean that they will want to collect more, not less, information.
They would much rather lose or refuse the business from many, many mid-size customers than risk the extremely punitive measures that the US government can impose on them.  For a similar reason, as OP has probably found, many foreign financial institutions simply won't do business with "US Persons" because it carries great potential risks from extraterritorial application of US laws.

Fun fact, I'm in the middle of dealing with the Australian KYC regulations for an investment.  The portal for entering your information for this specific investment requires that you have to have an Australian address.  I've been jumping through hoops to get them to recognize me.

@PeterM It's worse for businesses. Not that long ago you could open an account with all the proper documents and seal in hand the same day. Now they require multiple intrusive questionnaires and multiple levels of internal review for CYA err KYC. Weeks and weeks. Even for a purely domestic corporation that may do some business internationally.
